# How to regex params in fullPath Vue.js

Tags: javascript, regex

Hi everybody i have path on my Vue.js, so i'm need to replace /categories/.

```
axios ('apps/' + app.context.route.fullPath.replace('/categories/', ''))
```

here what i'm trying to do, but, here's the problem when i'm use this with path '/categories' without last '/', it don't work. Could you help me to match this string with regex with this two variants

Comment: In regex you make a character (and other Things) optional by adding a '?' after it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution would be to pass a regex as the first param of the replace method like this:

```
axios ('apps/' + app.context.route.fullPath.replace(/\/categories\/?/, ''))
```

The last part of the regex `\/?` means that the character `/` is optional.

Which will work for `/categories` and also for `/categories/`.

Hope it helps!